# Confusion about type casting in swift

Tags: swift

I was toying in the playground in xcode 7.3.1 with swift. I am a bit confused about the type casting in swift.

So, here is a bit of code that I tried.

```
class MediaItem {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Movie: MediaItem {
    var director: String
    init(name: String, director: String) {
        self.director = director
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

class Song: MediaItem {
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, artist: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

var movieItem = Movie(name: "GOT", director: "RRMartin")

movieItem.dynamicType                  //Movie.Type
(movieItem as? MediaItem).dynamicType  //Optional<MediaItem>.Type
var someItm = movieItem as! MediaItem  //Movie
someItm.dynamicType                    //Movie.Type
```

I've shown the output from the playground in the comment. Here you can see the type in each line.

Now according the docs of apple, `The conditional form, as?, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to.` As per the docs, I am trying to downcast to MediaItem, and I am getting the MediaItem as optional type.

But when I use force unwrap(that is `as!`) the returned type is `Movie`. But I wanted it to be `MediaItem`.

Also, another thing to notice is that, the type is actually changed. Some data are actually truncated. Because when I tried to access the `director` property which is present in the Movie, I cannot access it. As I've downcast it.

So, if the type is downcast, why the returned type is `Movie`? Shouldn't it be `MediaType`?

So, my question is this, when I type cast some derived class(`Movie`) to base class(`MediaType`), shouldn't the converted type be base class(`MediaType`)?

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY problem. Can you explain what it is you are actually trying to do? Why do you think you need a `MediaItem` when you know for a fact that the object is a `Movie`? The best quote is from WWDC "If you find yourself trying downcast type in Swift then you're fighting the type system and there is a much better approach that you're missing"

Comment: @Fogmeister, Actually I'm trying to understand the behavior. I just want to know why this is happening. Although maybe not in the same context, but say I want to convert a string to an Integer. The Type should be Integer right? not string.

Comment: In that specific case then no, you should not ever be casting from `String` to `Int`. You should be using the failable on `Int` that accepts a `String`. `if let int = Int("123") {...}` you should not be down casting here. In general there is no reason in Swift to be down casting like this.

Comment: Having said that. "Converting a String to an Int" is not any type of type casting. A String is not a subclass of Int (nor vice versa).

Comment: Yes, I was just giving an example. I know that it is unsafe. But, why they designed it that way? There should be a valid reason for this right?

Comment: You're not down casting at all, here, because you're going up the inheritance chain, which is always OK. `var someItm = movieItem as! MediaItem` should simply be `var someItm: MediaItem = movieItem`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths haha, true. I was thinking that too just didn't mention it.

Comment: Ok, I mixed up the downcast, upcast(if any), but I just want to know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is. If you really want to know about this particular behaviour then I'd suggest checking out (literally) the Swift git repo and seeing what comments are in there about this particular behaviour. If it's breaking something that you're trying to do then let us know and we can try to help you fix that.

Comment: @S_kar: The reason is that what you're trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense. In your example, a `Movie` already "is a" `MediaItem` because it's a subclass, so there's no need to "upcast" it. A subclass is always more specialized than its superclass, so you gain nothing by attempting to cast - you just use a superclass reference and restrict yourself to the superclass interface. This is obviously not true in the other direction, and this is why you sometimes might want to downcast.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths, Yes that makes much more sense about why the type was not changing. To Fogmeister, I did not break something actually. I saw this behavior and wanted to know the reason behind it actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamicType` tells you what the underlying type of the object is.  It doesn't tell you what the type of `var` currently referencing that object is.

For instance:

```
let a: Any = 3
a.dynamicType // Int.Type
```

Swift, of course, keeps track of these underlying types which is what allows you to later *downcast* a `MediaItem` to a `Movie` (if that is what it really is).

The confusion for you came when you did:

```
(movieItem as? MediaItem).dynamicType  //Optional<MediaItem>.Type
```

An *Optional* is it's own type.  It is an enumeration with two values: `.None` and `.Some(T)`.  The `.Some` value has an associated value that has its own dynamic type.  In your example, when you asked for the `dynamicType`, it returned the underlying type of the *Optional* which *is* `Optional<MediaItem>.Type`.  It didn't tell you what the dynamic type of the value associated with that *Optional* is.

Consider this:

```
let x = (movieItem as? MediaItem)
x.dynamicType    // Optional<MediaItem>.Type
x!.dynamicType   // Movie.Type
```